# Line chart Y axix value not show with single data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using high chart for my chart data display.My data shows correctly in graph but when my x axis have only one value then it's not show any value in y axis .

```
here is my code with single data

    http://jsfiddle.net/amarkotha366/uVSNP/

here is my code with multiple data

    http://jsfiddle.net/amarkotha366/UzkbH/
```

Now how I show y axis value when x axis have single value.

Comment: In the chart, it joins the two points on y-axis and creates lines. For multiple y axis data you can see lines but for single y axis data there is no another point to make a line hence you are getting single dot which is correct. There is no problem in your code.

Comment: any way to show value in y axis for single value @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: it is already showing as a single blue dot and no need to change any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have only one point, Highcharts are unable to calculate range on yAxis. In that case set [`minRange`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minRange) option, see: http://jsfiddle.net/uVSNP/4/